# Including the template doesn't return form field

Tags: django, forms

Here is my form

```
Class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    pub_from = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    pub_to = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
```

and my SearchView is

```
def SearchView(request):


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            pub_date_from = form.cleaned_data['pub_date_from']
            pub_date_to = form.cleaned_data['pub_date_to']

            #form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/admin/")

        else:
            return render_to_response("search_form.html", {"form":form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:

        form = SearchForm()
        context = {"form":form}
        return render_to_response("search_form.html", context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and my search_form.html is

```
<form action="" method="get">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

When I render the form singly it shows the form field and now when I inherit it to another template in `category.html` doing `{% include "search_form.html" %}` it only displays the submit button not the form field.

I dont know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: You have to pass `form` in the request context for that view as well

Comment: Can you post the view code for category.html?

Comment: If you are including the template in a view that doesn't include the form, this can not possibly work. Views render templates, templates don't call views.

Comment: How am I supposed to get the form then

Comment: Send it from whatever view is rendering the page where you're including the template.

Comment: Let `search_form.html` extend `category.html`. In `category.html` add a `{% block search_form %}` and in `search_form.html`, place your `<form ..` in the same block. 
And I prefer to return a `TemplateResponse(request, 'search_form.html', {'form': form})`, is easier than render_to_response.

Answer (score 0):

1. What is this???? `<form action="" method="get">`

the form method is a POST!

1. This was used by our throwing-stones ancestors:

`<input type="submit" value="submit">`

We now use `button` instead of `input`